# SQLite Beginner Question. Android Content resolver.update(...) insert(...)

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, where-clause

Do I explicitly write **WHERE** clause for **insert/updates?**

**Like so:**

`cr.update(uri, values, "WHERE _id="+id, null);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ContentResolver.update()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#update%28android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

About the `where` parameter:

> A filter to apply to rows before updating, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself).

Comment: This doesn't tell us exactly, how to write a WHERE clause for a ContentResolver. Could please somebody write an example?

Comment: This wasn't the question and it also already was applied as correct.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
String[] args = {String.valueOf(id)};
cr.update(uri, values, Data._ID + "=?", args);
```